# AWS SNS publish 404 error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, publish, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function where I am trying to publish a message to SNS topic:

Here is the code:

```
var params = {
    Message: origmessage,
    Subject: "Retrying posting URL",
    TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<acctid>:SampleTopic"
};
sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("SNS publish error")
        console.log(err, err.stack)
        console.log(data, data)
        console.log("RETRY PARAMS:" + params);
        context.fail(err);
    }
});
```

SNS publish error is cryptic as I am unable to find the root cause. Appreciate if someone can help me show a way to debug this.

Here is the error:

```
2017-01-19T00:41:13.947Z d440064d-dddf-11e6-abad-8de6d2739d36 {
  [404: null]
  message: null,
  code: 404,
  time: Thu Jan 19 2017 00:41:13 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  requestId: '0ENTKJ09RT82VE0SFEUJKT75NVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 404,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 26.97333029936999
}
'404: null
at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:45:29)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:668:14)
at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:670:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)'
```

Comment: The message is cryptic but all it really tells you is that you have a 404.  Does the topic exist..?  Does the function have permission to publish to it?

Comment: Yes. The topic exists and the function has permission to publish. I have a similar function that is able to publish. The message is null so not sure what to make out of it.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comments, when you use `AWS.config.update`, it affects all services.

By setting the `endpoint` parameter to the dynamodb endpoint, you are setting that endpoint for all services, including SNS.

This is an offending example where it says to specify the `endpoint` for dynamodb:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.Summary.html

Instead, the endpoint should be taken out of `AWS.config.update` and somehow specified in each service's constructor.

Comment: Yes.

// AWS configs
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var sns = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'});

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with your `endpoint` parameter to `update`. What if you try removing that?